# Change button wording depending on url

Tags: html, django

I am looking to change the wording of a button depending on a url path. I have tried to use some `{% if blocks %}` but unable to get it to work.

I have tried to the following if block

```html
<div class="form-group">
  {% if url == 'http://localhost:8000/client/<int:pk>/update/' %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
  {% else %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

This is my url in my apps urls.py

`path('client/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post-update"),`

Any help would be handy.

Comment: are you sure `url` contains the value you want to compare ? check https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/07/20/django-tip-7-how-to-get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template.html

Answer (score 0):

You can store the url in a temporary variable and then use it against if condition.

**In django template:**

```
{% url 'post-update' pk=1 as the_url %}
    {% if request.path == the_url %}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>  
    {% else %}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
    {% endif %}
```

Here request.path is your current url.

Comment: Thanks...but what if pk=1 is to change? Each entry will have a different primary key.